# Определить возможности ARM ядра для условной сборки проекта

Tags: c, gcc, arm

Интересует аппаратное умножение u64 = u32 * u32;
Часть вариантов ARM ядер не имеют умножения, часть имеют аккумулятор u32. Мне нужно определить точное соответствие ресурсов ядра, для переключения участков кода.
Есть наброски для распознавания математики одинарной и двойной точности, но работает плохо - за бортом остаётся слишком много архитектур. Есть подозрение, что где-то дальше все определения складываются в одну универсальную битовую структуру, но где и как - непонятно.

```
#if ((defined (__ARM_FP)) && (__ARM_FP == 14) && ARM_MATH_CM7)
#define _ARM_CODE_V   6
#elif ((defined (__ARM_FP)) && (__ARM_FP == 12) && ARM_MATH_CM7)
#define _ARM_CODE_V   5
#elif ((defined (__ARM_FP)) && (__ARM_FP == 4) && ARM_MATH_CM7)
#define _ARM_CODE_V   4
#elif ((defined (__ARM_FP)) && (__ARM_FP == 4) && ARM_MATH_CM4)
#define _ARM_CODE_V   3
#elif (ARM_MATH_CM3)
#define _ARM_CODE_V   2
#elif (ARM_MATH_CM0)
#define _ARM_CODE_V   1
#else
#define _ARM_CODE_V   0
#endif
```

Comment: А можно пример ядра, которое не поддерживает целочисленное умножение?

Comment: ARM cortex M0. Креме него есть большое разнообразие __ARM_ARCH:6 разной степени кастрации, некоторые вообще умножать не умеют.

Comment: Так, я смотрю в reference manual для Cortex-M0, там есть команда MULS. Это не то? Может Вы мне конкретное ядро укажите, которое не умеет в целочисленное умножение?

Comment: Просто, если multiplier все-таки есть, то может Вам достаточно проверять, какая это архитектура - 32- или 64-разрядная. Тогда можно просто проверять макросы `__arm__`, `__aarch64__`.

Comment: Не, если ARM имеет 64 бита регистры - то он 100% умеет всё, и ещё немного больше.

Comment: Для __ARM_ARCH:6 умножение - это дополнительная опция. В дополнение к умножению - результат в u64 - тоже считается дополнительной опцией. Я бегло посмотрел, команда "umull" имеет фиксированный формат на всех ARM чипах где может выполняться. Есть идея написать вставку, которую будет отключать пользователь, вместе со строкой условия. Но кажется, это не очень красиво.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140615/discussion-between-isnullxbh-and-avi-crak-home).

Comment: Делить и умножать не умеют китайские ARM чипы с ценником в 25 центов. Самые дешёвые. Чат открывается, но печатать некуда. stm32f0xx не умеет u64 = u32 * u32.

Comment: Так, мне кажется, мы зашли в тупик. Еще раз. Вы сказали: "Часть вариантов ARM ядер не имеют умножения, часть имеют аккумулятор u32". Меня интересовал именно первый вариант - ядра, в которых нет целочисленного умножения. В stm32f0xx (если верить спецификации), умножение есть. Мой поинт был в том, что если умножение есть везде, то почему нельзя просто проверять разрядность архитектуры? Если это 32 бита, то в общем случае у вас нет 64-битного результата, если 64 - в общем случае есть.

Comment: Я не могу назвать точную марку ARM без аппаратного умножения (любого). Отсутствие умножения я встретил в исходниках GCC, значит такие мк существуют. Подозреваю что основной критерий в поиске - цена.

Comment: Да, я поэтому и писал "в общем случае". Ну, если Вам попадется все же такой вариант, оставьте здесь ссылочку, пожалуйста. А сейчас я вынужден ретироваться.